# How to create a game background based on an array in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt

Recently I am starting to learn how to use Qt to build a easy maze game (QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene and etc...). The game's world should be generated through a random maze image (the black and white maze image you can download everywhere).

So I write some codes to read every pixels of an image and try to use that array to build a new maze world (for example, use some trees or some rocks to represent the black pixels...). I mean, I need to create a block for each point. This is important because I also need to build a path-finding function based on the image. So the world in the game should be strictly the same with the image.

I know I can use QGraphicsPixmapItem to create every blocks but it seems too stupid because for a 1000*1000 image I need to create 1M objects...

I am wondering if there are some solutions for it.

Thanks a lot

The codes how I generate the world. Title is a class which contain the grey value and the position of each pixel.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> World::createWorld(QString filename)
  {           
      //read image in, every pixel greyvalue is value of tile, black pixels are considered as impassable, gets value infinity
      world.load(filename);
      if (world.isNull())
        throw "Unable to read image file " + filename;
      rows = world.height();
      cols = world.width();
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Tile>> tiles;
      tiles.reserve(rows*cols);
      for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
          {
          float val = qGray(world.pixel(col,row))/255.0f;
          if (val > 0.0f)
            tiles.push_back(std::unique_ptr <Tile>(new Tile(col, row, val)));
          else
            tiles.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Tile>(new Tile(col, row, std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())));
          }
        }
      return tiles;
  }
```

Comment: You can show your code and explain better. If there are static elements, I recommend drawing it as a background of the QGraphicsScene, and if you are going to handle many elements then it eliminates the elements that are not in the view.

Comment: what is Tile???

Comment: As elylanesc also suggests in your place I would draw the maze as a single background image in the QGraphicsScene you can do that by drawing on a QPixmap and then set that as a background of the QGraphicsScene. But while you draw you also have to keep the plan of your maze in some ordered structured to be able to navigate and resolve it afterwards.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you!  Title is a class which contain the grey value and the position of each pixel.It is the minimum "unit" in the program, presenting a single pixel. It is a base class, which will be inherited by some other class like Protagonist and Enemy.

Comment: `Tile` or `Title`?

Comment: It seems unnecessary to have an object per pixel, that leads to an unnecessary expenditure of memory. I recommend you create a class that has the logic to generate all the pixels, then convert those pixels to a QImage or QPixmap and put it as the background of QGraphicsScene.

Comment: @eyllanesc Tile, sorry.